# Cascade Save - StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Having an issue with updating the NHibernate version. Current version is 3.3.1.4000 and trying to update to 4.
After updating the unit test which does save with cascade fails with:

```
NHibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [NHibernateTests.TestMappings.ProductLine#cdcaf08d-4831-4882-84b8-14de91581d2e]
```

**The mappings**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="NHibernateTests" namespace="NHibernateTests.TestMappings">
    <class name="Product" lazy="false" table="UserTest">
        <id name="Id">
            <generator class="guid"></generator>
        </id>

        <version name="Version" column="Version" unsaved-value="0"/>
        <property name="Name" not-null="false"></property>
        <property name="IsDeleted"></property>

        <bag name="ProductLines" table="ProductLine" inverse="true" cascade="all" lazy="true" where="IsDeleted=0" >
            <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write" />
            <key column="UserId" />
            <one-to-many class="ProductLine"  />
        </bag>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="NHibernateTests" namespace="NHibernateTests.TestMappings">
    <class name="ProductLine" where="IsDeleted=0" lazy="false">
        <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write" />
        <id name="Id">
            <generator class="guid"></generator>
        </id>

        <version name="Version" column="Version" unsaved-value="0"/>
        <property name="IsDeleted"></property>

        <many-to-one name="Product" class="Product" column="UserId" not-null="true" lazy="proxy"></many-to-one>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Classes:**

```
public class Product
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public IList<ProductLine> ProductLines { get; private set; }

    public Product()
    {
        ProductLines = new List<ProductLine>();
    }
}

public class ProductLine
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

The test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CascadeSaveTest()
{
    var product = new Product
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Name = "aaa",
        IsActive = true
    };
    var productLine = new ProductLine
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Product = product,
    };
    product.ProductLines.Add(productLine);

    using (var connection = new RepositoryConnection())
    {
        using (var repositories = new Repository<Product>(connection))
        {
            repositories.Create(product);
            //the below just calls the Session.Transaction.Commit();
            connection.Commit();   //NH3.3.1.400 passes, NH4 fails
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for you ideas in advance.

Comment: *I a bit remember that some time ago it was a real issue.. bug. The way to fix it could be to remove versioning on the item...*

Comment: In my case removing a version is not an option.
Though for the sake of this test, I removed the version from mappings and that still fails with the same exception.

Comment: May you try with a `set` rather than a `bag`? A bag can contain duplicates, but your case cannot. With your example, using a bag looks strange. Though I do not know why it causes it to fail with newer NH version.

Comment: Tried that, problem is not set or bag. Actually the problem is that NHibernate tries to update `productLine` before it was inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drilling it further down turned out that NHibernate4 has problems identifying whether it is a new entity or an already existent when concerned with `Cascade`.
With the scenario in question it was calling a SQL `Update` for the `ProductLine`, rather than `Create`.

It works fine with the below changes, however I'm quite puzzled with such a changes in between NHibernate versions.

**Change to ProductLine Mapping**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="NHibernateTests" namespace="NHibernateTests.TestMappings">
    <class name="ProductLine" where="IsDeleted=0" lazy="false">
        <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write" />
        <!-- here comes the updated line -->
        <id name="Id" type="guid" unsaved-value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
            <generator class="guid"></generator>
        </id>

        <version name="Version" column="Version" unsaved-value="0"/>
        <property name="IsDeleted"></property>

        <many-to-one name="Product" class="Product" column="UserId" not-null="true" lazy="proxy"></many-to-one>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Change to test method**

```
[TestMethod]
public void CascadeSaveTest()
{
    var product = new Product
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Name = "aaa",
        IsActive = true
    };
    var productLine = new ProductLine
    {
        Id = Guid.Empty,            //The updated line
        Product = product,
    };
    product.ProductLines.Add(productLine);

    using (var connection = new RepositoryConnection())
    {
        using (var repositories = new Repository<Product>(connection))
        {
            repositories.Create(product);
            connection.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess I have now understood what causes the error with NH 4. And If I am right, that is a bit contrived case causing this behavior to be hard to qualify as a bug.

In your example, products lines are mapped through a `bag`. A `bag` can contains duplicates, which requires an intermediate table between `Product` and `ProductLine`. (Something like a `ProductProductLine` table with an `UserId` (ProductId) column, and a `ProductLineId` column.)

You have set this intermediate table as being the `ProductLine` table. I suspect the commit to db causes NHibernate to insert the product, then the product line, then to try to insert the relationship by inserting again in `ProductLine` table. (You may check that by profiling SQL queries on your db.)

Things are a bit muddy, since [doc](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/collections.html#collections-mapping) states (emphasis is mine):

> table (optional - defaults to property name) the name of the
>   collection table **(not used for one-to-many associations)**

But then, how to honor the `bag` semantics allowing duplicates in the collection? From the same doc:

> A bag is an unordered, unindexed collection which may contain the same
>   element multiple times.

Anyway, within your example, you really should map your `one-to-many` with a `set`, as shown in [doc](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/collections.html#collections-onetomany).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="NHibernateTests" namespace="NHibernateTests.TestMappings">
    <class name="Product" lazy="false" table="UserTest">
        <id name="Id">
            <generator class="guid"></generator>
        </id>

        <version name="Version" column="Version" unsaved-value="0"/>
        <property name="Name" not-null="false"></property>
        <property name="IsDeleted"></property>

        <set name="ProductLines" inverse="true" cascade="all" lazy="true" where="IsDeleted=0" >
            <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write" />
            <key column="UserId" />
            <one-to-many class="ProductLine"  />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And change your collection type for using .Net fx 4 `System.Collections.Generic.ISet<T>`.

```cs
public ISet<ProductLine> ProductLines { get; private set; }

public Product()
{
    ProductLines = new HashSet<ProductLine>();
}
```

If this causes your trouble to disappear, it would mean something has changed in `bag` handling in NH 4. But should we consider this change as being a bug? Not sure, since using a `bag` in this case does not look right for me.